# Asterisk: Call dropped after 15mn

Tags: asterisk, voip

I'm getting a weird behavior on my Asterisk.
Calls are dropped after 15mn.
I'm getting the following error on the log file:

```
NOTICE[6301] chan_sip.c: Failed to authenticate on INVITE to '<sip:41907736445@188.32.64.1>;tag=ef7143klc9'
```

I'm using Asterisk Realtime. Calls a received from an operator and forwarded to external numbers throught an outbound trunk provided by anther operator.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sip.conf, try setting qualify=yes or keepalive=yes globally or for the trunk. Make sure to reload or just restart the service.

What version of Asterisk are you running?

Comment: I'm using Asterisk 1.8.32.3 Realtime

Comment: Did modifying the sip.conf do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Some carriers may send "confirmation" invite every X minutes. 
You can see more by enable sip debug

Answer (score 0):

Also if exactly at 15 min calls get dropped, then i would check the firewall to see whether there is timer set there that closes the connection after 15 min. I am speaking from experience.

Comment: No , it's not a firewall issue.
I have calls coming from two operators and the call drops is issued only with the second one

Comment: can you post a log snippet here with error included (like error 481, etc.) it could be actually 481 error due to forking.